# Design event dispatcher, event source, event watcher with type safety in C++

Tags: c++

Need some help in sorting out design options for simulation framework in C++ (no C++11).
The user creates an "event dispatcher" and registers interest (using "watchers") in occurrence of "events". The  dispatcher internally holds "event sources" which are used to detect event activation and manage notifications to watchers. There's a 1:1:1 mapping between watcher, event and event source classes.

I'd like to extend the system with

1. ability to register any sub-set of event watchers only in dispatcher (request unsupported notification will fail)
2. alternative implementations for event sources (e.g., one or multiple watchers per event)
3. extended event types (i.e., inheritance). Watcher and Source can handle sub-classes    as if they're the base type, albeit with reduced functionality.
4. user defined event, event source and event watcher. For completely new events

I've considered using "event type identifiers" (either strings or Base.Derived notation), it works but  doesn't feel correct (e.g., type safety relies on runtime integers, inheritance is limited, too many type casts...)
Would appreciate suggestions for code structure and mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the right situation to use `dynamic_cast`. It's only needed in one place.

All events inherit from a single base class, and all event handlers inherit from a (different) single base class. This makes all event sources and dispatchers uniform. Events are checked and filtered by the handlers in the base class.

[This](http://pastebin.com/ZBBcVLUd) is a rough 10-minute sketch of what the overall structure could look like. There are no event sources in the sketch since it's not entirely clear to me what they should look like. I just fire events from `main()`.

Comment: The dispatcher is a "facade" around different event sources (think of it as a collection). It adds handlers to the correct source, based on event type. How do I associate handlers to the correct source? To the best of my understanding, dynamic_cast will attempt conversion to arbitrary type and invoke handler if successful. Meaning it'll try all handlers.

Comment: "dynamic_cast will attempt conversion to arbitrary type and invoke handler if successful" -- Yes that's precisely what would happen. Is this bad for some reason?

Comment: I suspect his concern is the same as mine: instead of the dispatcher 'knowing' which handler to call for a given event (and calling them specifically), upon an event it calls _every_ handler and leaves it to each handler to 'know' whether to respond.  I'm too much of a novice to say that is good or bad, but it is counter-intuitive (to me anyway).

Comment: @tecu: the dispatcher "knowing" the type would needlessly complicate the design. If it can be demonstrated that trying all handlers hurts performance, then that's an argument in favor of looking for a more complicated solution. Until then, there's no need.